# Task.Factory.StartNew() Taskscheduler parameter

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

see: [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781658.aspx)

When i want to make a task to be long-running and also to be cancellable, If i am calling this method from ui,  how do i pass the taskscheduler parameter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not really obvious what the problem is. Why can't you just call:

```
CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken(false);
TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;
Task task = taskFactory.StartNew(action, token, 
                                 TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, scheduler);
```

Comment: i have revised my question, is this safe to pass .Default when i am calling this method from ui thread? considering this is a long running and blocking task.

Comment: @Benny: Your question itself still isn't very clear, as it doesn't mention TaskScheduler.Default. But yes, TaskScheduler.Default is fine to specify from the UI thread - but the task itself won't *run* on the UI thread.

Comment: sorry, I just want to make sure when i specify TaskScheduler.Default from UI thread, the task won't block the UI thread, thanks.